Is there a way to customize the serialization output of an XmlWriter?
I have the following that I'm using the serialize my XML document:
        XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sbXmlDoc, new XmlWriterSettings {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "  ",
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true
        });

That creates an instance of System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter which for some reason is internal so I can't extend / override it.  It outputs empty elements like <element /> instead of <element/>, putting the extra space in.  Is there any way I can customize the output so as to remove that extra space before the trailing slash?  I'm aware of XmlTextWriter but it seems to be recommended to use XmlWriter.Create() instead now.

You can try to use XSLT with a so called Identity Transform pattern. It seems that Saxon XSLT engine doesn't output spaces in XML elements without values.

Could you give that as an answer with example code?

You would need to download and install Saxon HE. Are you OK with that?

Is that really the only way to get rid of those spaces?  Seems really annoying

Unfortunately, Microsoft XML APIs are adding those spaces... Please see the requested solution below.

@Jez Why is it important that an empty element does not have a whitespace between the name and />? Both syntax is valid XML.

I have another thing rendering the same XML that doesn't add the space and I don't want the whitespace showing up in diff's, it's very annoying.

@Jez, if needed, we can have a quick call via MS Teams.

Why don't you simple do a basic string manipulation on the generated xml: generatedXml.Replace(" />", "/>")?

@PeterCsala I believe there are other places in XML where that string could occur, so that's unsafe for data integrity.

@Jez Could you please name any other places than self-closing tags?

<element>hello /> world</element>

The code is in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml/src/System/Xml/Core/XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.cs#L324, I think, you would need to have your own XmlWriter implementation overriding that method. There is some infrastructure in https://github.com/devlooped/Mvp.Xml/blob/main/src/Mvp.Xml/Common/XmlWrappingWriter.cs to wrap an existing XmlWriter and override/change some method but I am not sure there is a clean and safe way changing that behaviour.

Here is a generic solution by using Saxon and XSLT 3.0
The XSLT is one single line, it using a so called Identity Transform pattern.
It will work with any XML file.
You have a full control over indentation, XML declaration, encoding, BOM, etc.
Official Saxon HE downloads
You will find there the SaxonHE10-9N-setup.exe installation file in the Dotnet folder.
Input XML
<root>
   <city>Miami</city>
   <state />
</root>

XSLT 3.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <city>Miami</city>
   <state/>
</root>

c#
void Main()
{
    const string XSLTFILE = @"c:\Saxon-HE 10\IdentityTransform.xslt";
    const string INFILE = @"c:\Saxon-HE 10\input.xml";
    const string OUTFILE = @"c:\Saxon-HE 10\output.xml";

    // Create a Processor instance.
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    // Load the source document
    XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(INFILE));

    // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
    Xslt30Transformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(XSLTFILE)).Load30();

    // Create a serializer, with output to the standard output stream
    Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();
    serializer.SetOutputStream(new FileStream(OUTFILE, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));

    // Transform the source XML and serialize the result document
    transformer.ApplyTemplates(input, serializer);
    
    Console.WriteLine("Output written to '{0}'",  OUTFILE);
}

